# Como crear un ejecutable para compilar y correr programas Cobol en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, cobol

Deseo crear un archivo .sh o ejecutable el cual contenga la sentencia para compilar los programas Cobol y le pueda pasar como parámetro el nombre del archivo fuente para no tener que estar buscando o ejecutando el comando de compilación y ejecución. Con el parámetro que le pase a mi .sh o archivo de ejecución lo compile y lo ejecute en caso de no tener errores de compilación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, quiza en ASK Ubuntu, (otro sitio de Stack) te puedan ayudar, yo  busco allí las dudas sobre ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

No explicas que compilador estás usando pero supongo que es [OpenCOBOL](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/). Si es así necesitas lo siguiente:

**Para compilar y crear el ejecutable necesitas teclear:**

```
cobc -free -x -o hola.exe hola.cbl
```

**Para ejecutar:**

```
./hola.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer asi:

Creamos un archivo

**compile**

```
#!/bin/bash
# valida que se envie un parametro
if [ -z $1 ] ; then
    echo "[-] debes enviar el nombre del archivo";
    echo "./compile [nombre]";
    exit 1;
fi

# compilamos el archivo
cobc -x -o $1 $1.cbl

# valida que exista el archivo
if [ ! -f $1 ] ; then
    echo "[-] error de compilacion!";
    exit 1;
fi

# damos permiso de ejecucion
chmod +x $1

# ejecutamos
./$1
```

Damos permisos de ejecucion

```
chmod +× compile
```

**Ejecutamos:**

```
./compile lectura
```